# Hover to see secondary image in the fetured-product.liquid section on the Shopify Taste theme 4.0.0

Tags: shopify, liquid

I was wondering if there was a way to hover over the image in the featured product section to see the second image. I am using the Taste theme version 4.0.0. Thanks for the help. Let me know if you'll need more info.